# How to put sql query output from linux to a file in proper format?

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

[image]

I am running a shell scipt which connects to oracle and runs a select query and display data in above format (screenshot attached). I am redirecting this data to a file using spool command. How can I have data in a tabular format in my file like excel with a headers.

I have tried below options but its not working properly

```
set feedback off
set pages 0
set verify off
set pagesize 0 embedded on
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 200
SET UNDERLINE =
set markup on
set termout off
BREAK ON ROW SKIP PAGE
```

Comment: `set markup on` doesn't do it for you? Please specify *"it's not working properly"*. How is not working? Remember, you can see your screen and we can't. We only know what you tell us.

Answer (score 1):

I usually spool it into a file with a `.TXT` extension. In MS Excel, while opening that file, the **Text Import Wizard** opens and asks how to do that (which line is the 1st, which delimiter I used, ...) and everything fits into its own column.

If you save it as a `.CSV`, Excel will open it, but put all contents into column "A" (which is what you don't want).

This is my SET:

```
set termout off 
set trimspool on 
set echo off 
set verify off 
set autoprint off 
set serveroutput off 
set arraysize 1000 
set pagesize 0
set linesize 100
set long 10000
set numwidth 10
set feedback off
set colsep ';'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 12.2, just do

```
Set markup CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html) which will run all normal sqlplus things but has added in lots more above that.

Here's a quick example for what you are looking for.

```
sql klrice/klrice

SQLcl: Release 18.1 Production on Wed Feb 07 17:28:32 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Feb 07 2018 17:28:56 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


SQL> set feed off
SQL> set sqlformat csv
SQL> spool users.csv
SQL> select * from user_objects;
...rows.....
SQL> spool off
```